# Tornado routes no picked up by Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, routes, tornado

i follow  the tutorial based on a service i wan't to use ( Drone Deploy) :
https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/server_example.html
i made a topic on their forum for this issue 2 days ago.( and repo on Github)

But maybe someone can help me here.

I got an issue with an Heroku server app i do.
i use Python and the Tornado module.

The fact is i got a 404 error
My terminal ( when test it localy ) ask me :
"WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET / (::1) 0.75ms"

so the "GET" function is not working , maybe because of HTTP access control (CORS) i try many fix , but none worked.

Maybe i made something wrong ,or forgot something.

update : 
Recently someone of the Drone deploy said my tornado routes aren't being picked up by heroku.
After following many tutorial and read the Tornado documentation  i have no idea how to routes this.

the url of the server : https://stardrone-server.herokuapp.com/

this the code :

```
import os
import requests

import tornado.ioloop

import tornado.web


GEOCODE_FMT = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={address}&key={key}'


class GeocodeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """Proxy a call to the Google Maps geocode API"""

    def set_default_headers(self):
        # allow cross-origin requests to be made from your app on DroneDeploy to your web server
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.dronedeploy.com")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        # add more allowed methods when adding more handlers (POST, PUT, etc.)
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS")

    def get(self):
        api_key = os.environ.get("MyApiKey")
        address = self.get_query_argument("address")
        url = GEOCODE_FMT.format(address=address, key=api_key)

        # fetch results of the geocode from Google
        response = requests.get(url)

        # send the results back to the client
        self.write(response.content)

    def options(self):
        # no body
        self.set_status(204)
        self.finish()


def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/geocode/", GeocodeHandler)
    ])
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    application.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Maybe i missed something.
Any help, advices are appreciated

Thanks

John

Comment: I notice you are mounting you're route at `/gecode/` not at `/`. So the URL you should be hitting is https://stardrone-server.herokuapp.com/geocode/ - not https://stardrone-server.herokuapp.com/. I get a 400 Bad Request response. If you look at your logs you should see more about the cause of the 400 response. CORS is not required for what you're doing - if you're making a request to the Maps API from a server (as opposed to from a browser) there are no restrictions.

Comment: Hi Nik thanks for help. I fix and try your tips. i still have the same issue. I try several change at the line  : (r"/geocode/", GeocodeHandler) , by entering the adress. Now the log of Heroku ask me this. "WARNING:tornado.general:400 GET /geocode/ (10.167.190.210): Missing argument address " I'm Still try to fixing and understanding this routes.

Comment: I think your route is fine, the implementation of your request is the problem (as indicated by the 400 response). You're doing `self.get_query_argument("address")` - the "Missing argument address" error means you didn't pass this query parameter. You would need to do a request like https://stardrone-server.herokuapp.com/geocode/?address=new+york

Comment: this is the message i got , the issues is tornado : "2017-03-30T06:22:34.702703+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /geocode/?address=new+york (10.13.211.115) 2.19ms"

Comment: the log of heroku :       https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8716331/24499996/0387074a-1544-11e7-9966-599a4759dc84.png